# C# exception "This stream does not support seek operations." for HttpWebRequest method "PUT"

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

[image]I'm using PUT method to update some data. But my below code is not working.

The code:

```
var schemaRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(SchemaUri)) as HttpWebRequest;
schemaRequest.Method = "PUT";
schemaRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
schemaRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
schemaRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
schemaRequest.AddRange(1024);

string test = "<ArrayOfUpdateNodeRequest> <UpdateNodeRequest>  <Description>vijay</Description> <Name>Publishing</Name></UpdateNodeRequest></ArrayOfUpdateNodeRequest>";

byte[] arr = new byte[1024];
arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);
schemaRequest.ContentLength = arr.Length;

using (var dataStream = schemaRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
}
```

I'm getting the exception "This stream does not support seek operations." at GetRequestStream().

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace ?

Comment: You are helping too much.  Remove the ContentLength assignment.

Comment: @HansPassant - I don't think it is the cause (possible, but should work both ways to my understanding). Could be there something with server not accepting POST requests with ranges?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I uploaded exception stack trace.

Comment: Hi Hans & Alexei, I've tried both ways with/without add range and with/without contentlength.But I'm getting same exception :(

Comment: @user3194721, what you posted is not the stack trace. Please post the content of the StackTrace property of the exception.

Comment: Does the exception occur only when you look at the Position property in debug? If so, that's perfectly normal... Your code doesn't seem so access the Position of the stream, so it should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty clear, the steam doesn't support seeking.  Looking at the object in the debugger does not mean you *need* to seek--if you do, please provide an example.  You should simply be able to write to the stream for it to be sent to the host.  It doesn't make sense to be able to seek when you're sending a stream to a host (e.g, how do you seek back before a byte you've already sent over the wire to the host?).

If you need to seek locally, before sending to the host, create a memory stream and seek that way.  For example:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream new MemoryStream())
{
    // ... writes
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //... writes
    memoryStream.CopyTo(schemaRequest.GetRequestStream());
}
```